# Access recorded narrations programmatically

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

PowerPoint has a function named "Record narration". This records delays between user's button presses and then uses it to show automated slideshow, where animations, triggered to mouse-click, are shown according to those button clicks.

So, I want programmatically add this narrations. But in `Microsoft::Office::Interop::PowerPoint` I didn't find any useful data.  How can I access these narrations programmatically?

Comment: The following post claims to export the linked narration files. Maybe it can also help youfigure out how to import them: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00949_Export_linked_narration_sound_files_in_logically_named-numbered_order.htm

Comment: Thank you for you time, I`ll check that to find out if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timings are recorded in a slide-level tag called TIMING

The tag value might be something like |7|5.8|5.6

Meaning, roughly, Start, wait 7 seconds, move to next click, wait 5.8 seconds ... and so on.

To see e.g. the TIMING tag contents for slide 1, this:

```
Msgbox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Tags("TIMING")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is just what I needed.